# How to enable onDestroy-Logout method for entire app not just for Activity

Tags: android, ondestroy

onDestroy is use for any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. Hence, if a logout method is implemented within the onDestroy function, this will not work well for an app that has multiple activities, as the user will be logged out when they navigate through the app; esp when the user decides the push the back button.

How to implement the logout function within onDestroy method for the entire app; (when the user decides to terminate the app) instead for each individual ACTIVITY??

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("RootActivity:onDestroy()","******onDestroy:call on IdleLogout******");
    //Logout method
    //set loginbutton
    .....
}
```

Comment: It's not good to rely on `onDestroy()` method. You will not know when it will be called, sometimes OS will call it at later stage when it needs resources.

Comment: @Aniruddha so how do you suggest that the app logs the user out when the app has been destroyed/ terminated by the user? I wouldnt be able to use onTerminate(), since this is only applicable for emulators

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend `Activity` and create your own `BaseActivity` which in it's `onDestroy` method will implement your functionality.

Then you can extend you activities from your own `BaseActivity`!

```
public CustomActivity extends Activity{

   @Override
   public void onDestroy(){
       //etc...
   }

}


public ActivityA extends CustomActivity{}
```

Comment: What is the after "public ActivityA extends CustomActivity{}"? like do i need to implement the onDestroy method in there as well? and i understand that onDestroy() may not be guaranteed to be called as well. How do you ensure that it will be called on a consistent basis; like where would you need to implement the "finish()" method to?

Comment: Nope! If you implement it on your parent activity you don't have to!

Comment: Oh just saw the rest of your comment! In such case you need to study the Activity lifecycle to find out what suit's best for you! 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: what is the inter-relation between onPause and OnDestroy? why is it that when onPause is declared, onDeclared maynot be called?

Comment: You have to search google for this or just ask a new question! If i helped you accept my answer :)